# Вопрос по организации таблицы настроек адресов в PE

Tags: windows, pe

Таблица настроек адресов (base relocations table) представлена набором блоком. Каждый блок содержит поправки для 4К блоков содержимого файла (так понимаю, это число не всегда 4 равно и должно быть где-то в заголовке (или нет?); содержимого файла - от начала содержимого первой секции и до конца последней) и включает 2 значения: RVA настраиваемого блока и размер данного блока поправок, далее следуют сами поправки: 4 бита - тип, 12 бит - смещение от начального RVA (RVA настраиваемого блока).

У меня фундаментальные вопросы: а что из себя эта поправка представляет и зачем она нужна? Понимаю, что нужна вроде как для того, чтобы исправить какой-то упоминающийся в какой-то секции адрес. Но вообще изначально этот адрес из себя что представляет (просим пример к пояснениям хотя бы)? Если тот же RVA, то зачем его менять? Прибавить к нему базовый адрес загрузки да и всё... Что она из себя представляет тоже вроде как понятно: RVA адреса, который мы хотим исправить. А зачем делить файл на блоки по 4К? Почему бы просто не записать все поправки по порядку в кучу? Или это ради экономии места, чтобы RVA исправляемых адресов места много не занимали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В программе могут быть глобальные переменные или константы. Обращение к ним идет по фиксированным адресам (image base + rva), т.е. в если коде прописано `mov eax, [40123h]`, то `40123h` - это не rva, это image base + rva.

Если вдруг системному загрузчику вздумается разместить программу в памяти не по адресу image base, а по какому-то другому, то все явно прописанные в машинном коде адреса нужно исправить. Места, где нужно выполнить исправление, прописаны в таблице релокаций. Она есть не у всех exe-файлов, но она должна быть у всех динамических библиотек. Точной закономерности когда она нужна экзешнику, а когда нет, я не знаю. По опыту - у мелких экзешников, порядка десятков килобайт ее, как правило, нет. У крупных - десятки мегабайт и больше, она есть. Если у крупного экзешника ее убрать, то экзешник не запустится, по крайней мере на системах новее Windows XP.

Исправление адреса происходит следующим образом:

- Вычисляется дельта - фактический image_base минус image_base прописанный в заголовке файла
- По таблице релокаций находится место, по которому находится адрес, который нужно исправить
- К адресу прибавляется вычисленная дельта, старый адрес перезаписывается

Почему таблица релокаций организована именно так - трудно сказать, возможно действительно экономия места.

### Дополнение

- Насчет 4К - тут все дело в тех 12 битах, отведенных под смещение внутри блока. `1 << 12 == 4096`. Отвели бы больше бит под смещение внутри блока - можно было бы использовать блоки большего размера. В общем, все идет от структуры данных, используемой для хранения таблицы релокаций.
- `.bss` - после недолгого гугления - видимо да, неинициализированные данные (которые по факту инициализируются нулями). Как много нулей должно быть - размер любой секции должен быть кратен выравниванию, прописанному в заголовке PE файла. Т.е. фактический размер данных дополняется нулями до размера, кратного значению выравнивания.

  Вообще, секция с "настоящими" неинициализированными данными (когда нам не важно, что будет там записано на момент запуска), может вообще в файле отсутствовать, а просто быть прописанной в таблице секций, что есть такая секция, с нулевым физическим размером, таким-то размером в памяти и т.д. Так делает, например, flat assembler. Но умные С/С++ компиляторы видимо считают, что лучше неинициализированные данные на всякий случай обнулить.
- `.debug` - очевидно, там хранятся отладочные символы, если программа скомпилирована в режиме отладки.
- Инициализированные данные только для чтения - там могут быть например текстовые строки, таблицы переходов для `switch` (хотя они обычно прямо в секции кода прописаны), таблицы виртуальных методов вроде бы тоже там хранятся.

Имена секций на самом деле достаточно условны, разные компиляторы могут давать секциям разные имена. Физически вообще можно все свалить в одну секцию (в том числе таблицу импорта, главное чтобы она в data directory была прописана), и все будет работать.

Comment: Не могли бы заодно подсказать ещё по поре вопросов о секциях: что из себя представляет секция .bss (содержит неинициализированные данные и заполнена нулями, но какой размер должна иметь данная секция, т.е. "как много нулей там должно быть"?), .debug (такой секции вроде вообще нет в исполняемых PE файлах. ну а где тогда хранятся отладочные данные и что в них вообще такого полезного включается?) и .rdata (содержит инициализированные данные "только для чтения". это константы? что-то кроме констант там есть?)? Не хотелось бы просто отдельный вопрос задавать.

Comment: А кстати что на счёт значения 4К?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: _"`.debug` - очевидно, там хранятся отладочные символы, если программа скомпилирована в режиме отладки"_ - Ну это COFF Symbol Table + Auxiliary Symbol Records?

Comment: Вот в секции .data хранятся инициализированные данные. Как они выглядят? Просто куча значений переменных по порядку, к которым обращаются по их адресам в этой секции?

Comment: По отладочным символам не подскажу, я с ними не работал (в отличие от таблицы релокаций). По `.data` - да, все именно так.

Comment: Чем отличается понятие исполняемый образ и отображение? Много где в литературе указывается, например, что какая-то секция Image only, Object only. Object only - видимо, секция существует только в объектных файлах, Image only - исполняемый образ (сам файл), а отображение - это уже как секции PE файла были расположены в памяти.

Comment: Без понятия чем отличаются. Image only и Object only - да, скорее всего как вы написали.

Comment: А в каких случаях делается ссылка на .bss? Ну кроме неявной инициализации переменной.

Comment: Думаю, неявная инициализация чего-либо покрывает все случаи использования такой секции.

Comment: Ну по-сути под словом "что-либо" можно подразумевать лишь переменные и функции.

Comment: Секции с данными как правило не имеют разрешение на исполнение, поэтому функции отпадают.